# Why is a media upload breaking my app assocation (in firefox)?

Tags: google-drive-api

My javascript app creates a file and then uploads the media content. In Chrome, everything is hunky dorey. In Firefox, the act of uploading media is somehow breaking the association Drive holds between the file and my app, such that the icon is no longer my application icon (it's the default Google blue box) and clicking to open the file gives an error page.

So the steps are ...

1. Create the file (POST to /files)
2. Observe in Drive that the file exists and is displayed with my application icon
3. Upload the file contents (PUT with uploadType=media and convert=false)
4. Observe in Drive that the file's icon is now the Google blue

If I do **exactly** the same in Chrome, at step 4, the file is still associated with my app and displays my app icon.

Here is the media PUT from Chrome (ie the working one)

```
PUT https://content.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2SERMMEFXMkdiOWM?uploadType=media&convert=false&useContentAsIndexableText=true&key=AIzaSyCt2bxTnrxo_IGvSUCBBAN_-29HJnzX_MU HTTP/1.1
:host: content.googleapis.com
x-origin: http://foo.myapp.appspot.com
x-javascript-user-agent: google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0-beta
x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-AU;q=0.6
authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQq1wAGltlEsnGKr6Dgtgkvp4zHCJsNTrXohnqrRmm3Ji8Yb14
x-referer: http://foo.myapp.appspot.com
x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(X11%3B%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F28.0.1500.95%20Safari%2F537.36&platform=Linux%20x86_64&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(X11%3B%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F28.0.1500.95%20Safari%2F537.36
referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.l49lMhuyXyk.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DEQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTOvD2NxxPLz0HiGHMXTek7IhOVTHg
content-length: 9

:version: HTTP/1.1
origin: https://content.googleapis.com
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
:path: /upload/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2SERMMEFXMkdiOWM?uploadType=media&convert=false&useContentAsIndexableText=true&key=AIzaSyCt1bxTnrxo_IGvSUCBBAN_-29HJnzX_MU
content-type: text/html
accept: */*
:scheme: https
:method: PUT

Query String 
uploadType=media
&convert=false
&useContentAsIndexableText=true
&key=AIzaSyCt2bxTnrxo_IGvSUCBBAN_-29HJnzX_MU
```

and here is the media PUT from Firefox (ie. the one that breaks the file association)

**firefox**

```
PUT /upload/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2UFZxbjExd0dGeTQ?uploadType=media&convert=false&useContentAsIndexableText=true&key=AIzaSyCt2bxTnrxo_IGvSUCBBAN_-29HJnzX_MU HTTP/1.1
Host: content.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQrG_PQOmEZD4cBwgrjiNKNZUBc2RzAnOTmZwTJReX664MWvu8
X-ClientDetails: appVersion=5.0%20(X11)&platform=Linux%20x86_64&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(X11%3B%20Linux%20x86_64%3B%20rv%3A21.0)%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F21.0
X-JavaScript-User-Agent: google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0-beta
X-Origin: http://foo.myapp.appspot.com
X-Referer: http://foo.myapp.appspot.com
X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable: base64
Referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.l49lMhuyXyk.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DEQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTOvD2NxxPLz0HiGHMXTek7IhOVTHg
Content-Length: 12
Connection: keep-alive

convert false
key AIzaSyCt2bxTnrxo_IGvSUCBBAN_-29HJnzX_MU
uploadType  media
useContentAsIndexableText   true
```

The responses are below. The only difference between the return Item json is that the Chrome version has a mimetype "text/html" whereas Firefox has mimetype "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

**firefox response**

```
   Content-Length 2986
    Content-Type application/json
    Date Sat, 24 Aug 2013 10:44:37 GMT
    Etag "NaUPR8AuDOKgpQqXUqmAHnRC-Nk/R_dzQ2tl2e997lu1SqOGTX63YoE"
    Server HTTP Upload Server Built on Aug 7 2013 16:51:13 (1375919473)
    X-Firefox-Spdy 3


"kind":"drive#file",
"id":"0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc",
"etag":"\"NaUPR8AuDOKgpQqXUqmAHnRC-Nk/NM5C-3sulAfFZA1V-IIsA-E9_AA\"",
"selfLink":"https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc",
"webContentLink":"https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc&export=download",
"alternateLink":"https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc/edit?usp=drivesdk",
"iconLink":"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_generic_list.png",
"thumbnailLink":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1KctCx9tjxe6vSn7piLUzfYQuNKQVzMUd6Phn8dTdlHKfQlQsXi77PyOOLkwS-0q3g=s220",
"title":"burcu",
"mimeType":"text/html; charset=UTF-8",
"labels":{
    "starred":false,
    "hidden":false,
    "trashed":false,
    "restricted":false,
    "viewed":true
},
"createdDate":"2013-08-24T10:44:12.851Z",
"modifiedDate":"2013-08-24T10:44:36.440Z",
"modifiedByMeDate":"2013-08-24T10:44:36.440Z",
"lastViewedByMeDate":"2013-08-24T10:44:36.440Z",
"parents":[
    {
        "kind":"drive#parentReference",
        "id":"0B6B-RNrxsCu2RVVQZ1NFWGZYUW8",
        "selfLink":"https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc/parents/0B6B-RNrxsCu2RVVQZ1NFWGZYUW8",
        "parentLink":"https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2RVVQZ1NFWGZYUW8",
        "isRoot":false
    },
    {
        "kind":"drive#parentReference",
        "id":"0B6B-RNrxsCu2MFZ0dEx6a2xEQU0",
        "selfLink":"https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc/parents/0B6B-RNrxsCu2MFZ0dEx6a2xEQU0",
        "parentLink":"https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2MFZ0dEx6a2xEQU0",
        "isRoot":false
    }
],
"downloadUrl":"https://doc-0k-54-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/i6kcvi4n5dug3hk78lqkpogagkdpecs6/krhjojomqafnrdg6943a1fhtnfjg4b8v/1377338400000/15125351317662028975/15125351317662028975/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true",
"userPermission":{
    "kind":"drive#permission",
    "etag":"\"NaUPR8AuDOKgpQqXUqmAHnRC-Nk/ajH3QRzRTY6aEeYY5k2JAipDckI\"",
    "id":"me",
    "selfLink":"https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc/permissions/me",
    "role":"owner",
    "type":"user"
},
"originalFilename":"burcu",
"fileExtension":"",
"md5Checksum":"47088846bea0768b700fa76afc1e2aee",
"fileSize":"6",
"quotaBytesUsed":"6",
"ownerNames":[
    " Demo"
],
"owners":[
    {
        "kind":"drive#user",
        "displayName":" Demo",
        "isAuthenticatedUser":true,
        "permissionId":"15125351317662028975"
    }
],
"lastModifyingUserName":" Demo",
"lastModifyingUser":{
    "kind":"drive#user",
    "displayName":" Demo",
    "isAuthenticatedUser":true,
    "permissionId":"15125351317662028975"
},
"editable":true,
"copyable":true,
"writersCanShare":true,
"shared":false,
"appDataContents":false,
"headRevisionId":"0B6B-RNrxsCu2MWN5clphQUlBNStwM1FLTWZWS3R0RkViVkh3PQ"
```

}

**chrome response**

```
content-length:
2977
content-type:
application/json
date:
Sat, 24 Aug 2013 10:48:29 GMT
etag:
"NaUPR8AuDOKgpQqXUqmAHnRC-Nk/pESqU9sAUSQgLet1Hkz2wJT0Nyw"
server:
HTTP Upload Server Built on Aug 7 2013 16:51:13 (1375919473)
status:
200 OK
version:
HTTP/1.1


{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc",
"etag": "\"NaUPR8AuDOKgpQqXUqmAHnRC-Nk/7kdHmkAGWmpQ_v_pNZFbF-GLMic\"",
"selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc",
"webContentLink": "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc&export=download",
"alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc/edit?usp=drivesdk",
"iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_generic_list.png",
"thumbnailLink": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/AXTF6nVY78BZi00eTaAEwmdTfeXVC5Ny3zYEIVEPOTwPNGqy7LC9dKiqzZBg9-q3LA=s220",
"title": "burcu",
"mimeType": "text/html",
"labels": {
"starred": false,
"hidden": false,
"trashed": false,
"restricted": false,
"viewed": true
},
"createdDate": "2013-08-24T10:44:12.851Z",
"modifiedDate": "2013-08-24T10:48:27.913Z",
"modifiedByMeDate": "2013-08-24T10:48:27.913Z",
"lastViewedByMeDate": "2013-08-24T10:48:27.913Z",
"parents": [
{
"kind": "drive#parentReference",
"id": "0B6B-RNrxsCu2RVVQZ1NFWGZYUW8",
"selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc/parents/0B6B-RNrxsCu2RVVQZ1NFWGZYUW8",
"parentLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2RVVQZ1NFWGZYUW8",
"isRoot": false
},
{
"kind": "drive#parentReference",
"id": "0B6B-RNrxsCu2MFZ0dEx6a2xEQU0",
"selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc/parents/0B6B-RNrxsCu2MFZ0dEx6a2xEQU0",
"parentLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2MFZ0dEx6a2xEQU0",
"isRoot": false
}
],
"downloadUrl": "https://doc-0k-54-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/i6kcvi4n5dug3hk78lqkpogagkdpecs6/krhjojomqafnrdg6943a1fhtnfjg4b8v/1377338400000/15125351317662028975/15125351317662028975/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true",
"userPermission": {
"kind": "drive#permission",
"etag": "\"NaUPR8AuDOKgpQqXUqmAHnRC-Nk/ajH3QRzRTY6aEeYY5k2JAipDckI\"",
"id": "me",
"selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6B-RNrxsCu2cjlldTNoV01JVHc/permissions/me",
"role": "owner",
"type": "user"
},
"originalFilename": "burcu",
"fileExtension": "",
"md5Checksum": "423f5e2804f551616956ca8cb4a684b0",
"fileSize": "9527",
"quotaBytesUsed": "9527",
"ownerNames": [
" Demo"
],
"owners": [
{
"kind": "drive#user",
"displayName": " Demo",
"isAuthenticatedUser": true,
"permissionId": "15125351317662028975"
}
],
"lastModifyingUserName": " Demo",
"lastModifyingUser": {
"kind": "drive#user",
"displayName": " Demo",
"isAuthenticatedUser": true,
"permissionId": "15125351317662028975"
},
"editable": true,
"copyable": true,
"writersCanShare": true,
"shared": false,
"appDataContents": false,
"headRevisionId": "0B6B-RNrxsCu2Zmg1M0todDBPcERUREtmTjZuQjlCQjJIOUVJPQ"
}
```

Comment: to add to/confirm the weirdness, if I update the content in Chrome, the association is re-made. If I then re-update in Firefox, the association is broken again.

Comment: What are your request bodies and responses for each?

Comment: The requests were in the original question. I've edited it to include the response headers and body. The only difference in the response appears to be the mimeType property. This seems to reflect the Content-type header of the respective requests.

Comment: It's the mimeType!   I went the the api console and added "text/html; charset=UTF-8" as a mime-type that my app can open, and it now shows in the Drive webapp as being associated with my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question by saying this is a bug.

To summarise, using the GAPI Javascript client with Firefox to update content is causing the mime-type in Drive to include the character set (eg. "text/html; charset=UTF-8"). Because this doesn't match the mime-type declared in the API Console ("text/html"), the Drive webapp doesn't associate the file with my application.

The bug could be deemed to be in one of three places:-

1. It could be a GAPI JS client bug that it is setting the content-type header to be "text/html; charset=UTF-8".
2. It could be a Drive SDK bug, that the file mime type should always be the one I explicitly declared when I created the file, and should ignore the mime type header of any media uploads. Or it could be considered that the Drive SDK should strip the character set from the content-type header before using it to set the mime type on the file.
3. It could be a Drive webapp bug, that it should consider "text/html" and "text/html; charset=UTF-8" to be the same mime type.